# Sheets conditional formatting if contains text from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google sheet which has a column for business name (A) and a column for city (B).  I would like to set conditional formatting such that if the city name is contained within the business name on the same row, the business name will be highlighted.

[list example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRkhr.jpg)

Every row contains different business/city data, and there are thousands of rows.  I need one formula that will work for the whole sheet.

I know how to do it if the city name and business name are exactly the same `=$A$2:$A=$B2`, but struggling to figure out how to do it if just a portion matches.  Putting an asterisk before $B2 broke the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=REGEXMATCH ($A2,$B2) would do the work too!

Comment: It will not work if city in company for example will be in uppercase

Comment: Add LOWER to each cell `=REGEXMATCH (LOWER($A2),LOWER($B2))`

Comment: Thank you that worked great!  I'll put the lower stuff in too JIC

Answer (score 0):

Use `SEARCH`:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(B2),A2)),B2<>"")
```

with range starting from `A2`. You search if `A2` contains text from `B2` and returns starting number if found. So if it is a number then `ISNUMBER` returns `TRUE`

Result:

[image]